# Code throws System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to submit a form and i run into a 500 internal server error. When i debug the piece of code that is causing this throws an System.InvalidOperationException:

```
var description = _context.Malfunction.Single(d => d.Description == newReport.ReportDescsription).ToString();
```

this is my jquery for the description var:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        vm = {
            movieIds: [],
            ReportDescription: null
        };
function applyChanges() {
        vm.ReportDescription = document.getElementById("descriptionReport").value;
        if (vm.ReportDescription == "") {
            vm.ReportDescription = null;
        }
    }
```

ajax post:

```
 $.ajax({
 url: "/api/Malfunctions",
 method: "post",
 data: vm
 })
```

Comment: Can you post exception details? Explain what message displayed with thrown `InvalidOperationException` by editing your question.

Comment: Instead of Single, you should do FirstOrDefault() and also instead of ToString() you should use Convert.ToString(), this will handle null exceptions

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto After changing it to FirstOrDefault i get the null exception, Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @TechGirl when i try Convert.ToString() it tells me to simplify it to only toString()

Comment: @IlirAs That's certainly NRE (`NullReferenceException`). Using `ToString()` method while the query returns no results will thrown NRE (check if the query result is null first).

Comment: @IlirAs yes, at times like these, where you think you might face a null situation, you should use Convert.ToString, also Single and SingleOrDefault will throw error if no records are returned, so you should opt for FirstOrDefault. Also you can verify first if the query returns null, if not then you can convert to avoid this scenario

Comment: @TechGirl Why is it returning it as null, i dont understand and this is the code i am currently using when getting this error: var description = _context.Malfunction.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Description == newReport.ReportDescsription).ToString(); //what should i change

Answer (score 0):

```
var description = _context.Malfunction.Select(des => desc.Description).FirstOrDefault(d => d.Description == newReport.ReportDescsription);
if(description != null)
{
   var str = description.toString();
}
```

Here you will first verify if the data is returned or is it null, if not null then you can continue with your code.

Edit: Added Select to only return description, assuming Malfunction has more columns

Comment: Error still persists, Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'test1.Models.Malfunction' to 'string' Warning CS0162 Unreachable code detected in HomeController

Comment: @IlirAs what is the result in description variable?

Comment: It doesn't have a value because the code doesnt build at all

Comment: @IlirAs so comment that code, and share what is the value in description once the query is executed.

Comment: description value is equal to null. Idk why my reply wasn't sent earlier..

Comment: @IlirAs updated my answer, Assuming the Malfunction table has more columns, return only description, and then do a ToString.

Comment: It wont build, throws 2 errors:1.Error CS1061 'Malfunction' does not contain a definition for 'description' and no extension method 'description' accepting a first argument of type 'Malfunction' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?), 2. Unreachable code detected at HomeController.

Comment: @IlirAs edited the code, First char needed to be caps, I dont have access to your table/context. You should know which columns exists

Comment: at d => d.Description this: Error CS1061 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Description' and no extension method 'Description' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) and yes a column named Description does exist in my table